# Apache worker mpm, one process and many threads: understanding performance

Tags: apache-2.2, process, threads, mpm-worker

Got a mod_perl-written serverside program.
Im using shared apache worker mpm memory with one process only, and ~ 60 threads.
Im using locks to temporary secure the access to the shared memory, just 0.1s out of 1.7s are locked time though.

The problem is that i get the same speed on 10 sequential requests compared to 10 concurrent requests.

my stress-script fire up *n* number of heavy URL process-requests with 0.1s delay between each. The number in brackets is the request number.

```
perl stressTestServer.pl n=1
DONE  ( 0 ) > 1.778257 sek 

perl stressTestServer.pl n=5
DONE  ( 3 ) > 8.71926 sek 
DONE  ( 0 ) > 8.85207 sek 
DONE  ( 1 ) > 8.976061 sek 
DONE  ( 4 ) > 9.119936 sek 
DONE  ( 2 ) > 9.218552 sek 

perl stressTestServer.pl n=10
DONE  ( 9 ) > 8.840539 sek 
DONE  ( 7 ) > 9.130133 sek 
DONE  ( 8 ) > 9.271598 sek 
DONE  ( 6 ) > 9.873936 sek 
DONE  ( 5 ) > 10.02668 sek 
DONE  ( 4 ) > 18.169001 sek 
DONE  ( 3 ) > 18.432776 sek 
DONE  ( 2 ) > 18.617186 sek 
DONE  ( 1 ) > 18.775277 sek 
DONE  ( 0 ) > 18.821972 sek
```

is this normal for this setup? 
this is tested on a dual-core. moving to a quad core, what performance difference can i expect with this setup? 
I have a hard time believing more cores will help here.. 
feels like serialized execution could be more efficient than concurrent threads.

tx for input!